# XCode/Swift OSX. Select and Edit Cells in ViewBased NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, edit, nstableview

Before I ask my OSX related question please allow me to describe a feature in MS Windows.

If I create a Windows application in MS Visual Studio where the application contains a simple DataGrid the user can simply click into a cell, edit the contents and use the keyboard up/down arrow keys to move quickly out of the cell to the next one. keying out of the cell triggers the EndEdit event. Using the up/down arrow keys like that a user can quickly move down a column editing values without pressing Enter or using the mouse.

I'm trying to do the same with OSX XCode/Swift. Using the mouse to click into a cell and edit is no problem. But it seems as though I have to click the cell twice to get it selected for editing and then after editing I have to press enter or click another cell. I can't simply use the up/down arrow keys to key out of the cell.

Is that simply the way OSX works? I mean I'm making an OSX application so I want it to behave like a native application but it just seems like a lot of entering and clicking is required if, for example, the user was going to edit a few cells.

Are there any properties I need to set in the ViewBased TableView?

Sorry about the long email - I hope I've explained it though.

Thanks
Ian

Comment: I'd love to see what you have tried so far. Because, theoretically, it's entirely possible to achieve your behaviour. Just imagine OSX' Excel (Numbers). You can definitely create something similar.

Comment: So far I've just tried toggling properties in the IDE Attributes Inspector. There's a couple related to how a cell is selected. And there's one related to how the EditEnd event is fired. But I just can't see anything related to how the focus can be taken out of the cell - ie anything that would allow the user to press the up/down arrow keys to move to the next cell. Maybe I just need to trap keypresses and programmatically shift up/down a row and give edit focus to the next cell - ie roll my own - now that, as you say, I'm not trying to make a non-mac-like UI.

Comment: You can not achieve that behaviour by simply setting IB flags afaik. Catching the keyPress events programmatically seems to be the right way. I'd go the same tour.

Answer (score 1):

After much head scratching I've got something that appears to work exactly as I want.

myTableView is on an NSViewController.
In the NSViewController's viewDidLoad() I've got this:

```
super.viewDidLoad();

NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(NSEventMask.KeyDownMask, handler:{
    (event: NSEvent) in
    self.myTableView.keyDown(event);

    switch(event.keyCode)
    {
        case 36:
            return nil;
        case 125:
            return nil;
        case 126:
            return nil;
        default:
            return event;
     }
})
```

I have to confess I'm not 100% sure but my thoughts were that the default behavior of the tableView is for the up/down arrow keys to move the row selection up or down a row but that doesn't happen when a cell is being edited. When the text cell has edit focus the up/down keys simply shift the cursor to the start/end of the cell (ie move the cursor within the cell). Not the behavior I want so I thought if I could swallow (make nil) those events within the cell then the arrow keypress would bubble up to the tableview and it would do the up/down row select - if you see what I mean.

Anyway - no matter where my thoughts were - this does seem to work exactly as I want and when the edit focus arrives on the next cell it gets instant edit focus. Basically working just like it does in programs such as excel and numbers etc.